# Why I can't set my Dojo DateTextField?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to open a form having a DateTextField which must be populated with record from database. And I am having no luck of doing it. I already test my code this way :

```
dijit.byId("jurnal_date").attr("value", new Date(2011,1,1))
```

Just to test the basic way of setting a DateTextField. But the value won't get entered into DateTextField. What did I do wrong? Here is the DateTextField declaration:

```
<input type="text" name="jurnal_date" id="jurnal_date" required="true" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I just resolved my own problem. Here is the answer :

```
newJournalDialog.show();
dijit.byId("jurnal_date").attr("value",dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(jurnal.date))
```

So, we can only set the value of a DateTextField, after its dialog/form is shown. 
Well, this is my conclusion after solving this problem :)

Thanks.